# beginner scala pattern matching - split a#b by # and assign to Map

Tags: scala

I want to write some scala code that does the following:-

Converts a list of ["a#b","c#"] to a map with the portion before # as key and the portion after # as the value if the value exists.

So, for the above array the map would be:

```
{
 "a" => "b" // no "c" because it does not have a value.
}
```

What is the most elegant way to express this in scala style? Also, how are null checks performed in scala?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val list = List("a#b", "c", "d#e", "")

scala> list.map(x => x.split("#")).filter(_.size == 2).map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1))).toMap
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> b, d -> e)
```

Comment: I agree this is concise. But is this elegant as per Scala standards? Is it usually the case that a ton of stuff happens in a single line in scala?

Comment: @ajay You can put the intermediate values on multiple lines if you like. `split` and  `filter` and pretty idiomatic here. It gets a little messy because `split` on each string leaves you with `List[Array[String]`. Each `Array`(from `split`) gets converted to a `Map` and then you combine the maps. There's other ways to approach it but with `split` it gets messy.